# What is the best way to detect whether a java API call successfully completed or not

Tags: java, google-compute-engine

I'm using following code to add a target pool to Google compute engine in java using [Google Compute Engine Java API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries#google_apis_java_client_library).

```
Operation operation = compute.targetPools().insert(PROJECT_ID, REGION_NAME, targetPool).execute();
```

I need to make sure that target pool is successfully added or not before execute the next line. What is the best way to do this in [Google Compute Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries#google_apis_java_client_library)?

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion on checking the status on Operation?

Comment: Hi, Yes I tried now. But it seems like the operation status newer change. It always says pending. But I can see the target pool has created in GCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait until operation will be in status DONE and then check if it has no errors. To do that you need to do polling on the operation using the compute."operations"().get() - I've put operations in quotation marks because there are three types of operations: global, regional and zonal and each of them has its own service: globalOperations(), regionOperations() and zoneOperations(). As targetPools are regional resource, operation created by insert is also regional so you need to use compute().regionOperations().get(). Code:

```
while (!operation.getStatus().equals("DONE")) {
   RegionOperations.Get getOperation = compute.regionOperations().get(
              PROJECT_ID, REGION_NAME, operation.getName());
   operation = getOperation.execute();
}
if (operation.getError() == null) {
  // targetPools has been successfully created
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is correct. I have checked the status of a local operation object. That's why it showed always 'PENDING'.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to check the status

```
while(!operation.getStatus().equals("DONE")) { 
  //wait
  System.out.println("Progress: " + operation.getProgress());
}
  // Check if Success
if(operation.getError() != null) {
  // Handle Error
} else {
  // Succeed with Program
}
```

Comment: It seems like this is correct. But the operation status is never updates to DONE. I think that may be a bug in GCE API.

Comment: Updated my answer, because operation.getStatus() returns a String and not an Enum as I thought, so comparing with equals("DONE") should work. Btw. what is operation.getProgress() showing? Is getStatus() really "PENDING" all the time?

Comment: Hi daniel,
yes it shows always pending. Not updating to DONE even though the resource has completed successfully in GCE.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a try/catch block?
You could do something like:

```
try
{
   Operation operation = compute.targetPools().insert(PROJECT_ID, REGION_NAME, targetPool).execute();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //Error handling stuff
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have already tried this but it is not possible to determine whether operation got succeeded or not by using a try catch block